# First number to determine number of elements in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, element

For example, in the first line the user types a number, and that number will determine the number of elements in a list.

Comment: You should give more details about what you want the code to do. Will the list be initialized after the user specifies a number? What is the goal of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific with the question. Yes, I want the list to be initialized after the user specifies a number.

Comment: Then check @BoarGules answer, as it tells you exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 2):

Python lists are dynamic. You can set them up with a given number of elements but there is nothing to stop subsequent code adding or removing them and so changing the size of the list.

You can do something like:

```
size = int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
mylist = [None] * size
print(mylist)
```

which will give the output

```
[None, None, None]
```